# Render multiple lines for each item dropdown in React

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

How can I render multiple lines for each item in the dropdown. Ex: I need to display address1 in first-line and city, the state in second line for each item in the dropdown. \n and \br doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```js
React.render(
    <Dropdown label="Dropdown Label">
      <DropdownItem label="1 main street \n  sacramento, california" value="Number 1" />
      <DropdownItem label="2 main street \n  stockton, california" value="2" />
    </Dropdown>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Comment: Is this some UI library or just custom Components?

Comment: This is custom component

Comment: Hi,  My design needs to have drop down and when they click the dropdown it should expand in this format

Comment: My design needs to have drop down and when they click the dropdown it should expand in this format                                                                           
                                                                                                                        
 233  (dropdown)

233 1 main street  (list view)
       sacramento

234  2 main street    (list view)
         stockton

Comment: sorry i don't understand format, do you have a image (whats list view in this) ?

Comment: and what's 233 ? upload a image on paper and visualie ur stuff ,  and host it in here https://imgbb.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript's [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. You can have city names as an array and have their position index as the key and name of the city as value. More information can be found in React [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html) and an example can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/GjPyQr?editors=0011). Example below:

```
  function Filter(props){
  const Items = ['All', 'Car', 'Truck', 'Convetible'];
  const MappingItems = Items.map((Item) => <option>{Item}</option> );
  return (
    <div style={divStyle}>
      New Only <input type="checkbox" /><br /><br />
      Select Type <select>
        {MappingItems}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Filter />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, Does it display the drop down list in this format. It needs to show two drop down values in the format                                                                                   1 main street                                                                                      
 sacramento, california
  2 main street                                                                                      
 Stockton, california

Comment: Go to the link below and there you will find how I have displayed the names of different types of vehicles using the map method. Hope it helps.
Link: https://codepen.io/savi_dulai/pen/gOORzxX

Comment: My design needs to have drop down and when they click the dropdown it should expand in this format                                                                           
                                                                                                                        
 233  (dropdown)

233 1 main street  (list view)
       sacramento

234  2 main street    (list view)
         stockton

Answer (score 1):

If you have a dropdown list like the following:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

In most cases, this dropdown list will be dynamic, Its better to keep it in an array and then use javascript higher order function to map over it

```
const optionsList = [
   {
      name: 'Volvo',
      value: 'volvo',
   },
   {
     name: 'Saab',
     value: 'saab',
   },
  // And the no of drop down items could be dynamic
];

// Now in your render method
React.render(
    <select onChange={onChangeFunction}>
    {optionsList.map(option => (
      <option value={option.value} key={option.name}>{option.name}</option>
    ))}
    </select>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

// In this way your dropdown will appear as a dropdown list on the newline without using breaks or newlines
```

P.S. Dont forget to miss the key while mapping options. React will thank you ;)

And now you have all the flexiblity to make this select your custom component by giving it styles of your choice.

Comment: My design needs to have drop down and when they click the dropdown it should expand in this format                                                                           
                                                                                                                        
 233  (dropdown)

233 1 main street  (list view)
       sacramento

234  2 main street    (list view)
         stockton

Answer (score 0):

here you go , as per your requirement:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
const DropdownItem = props => {
  return (
    <option label={props.value} value={props.label}>
      {props.value}
    </option>
  );
};

class Dropdown extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = e => {
    this.setState({ value: String(e.target.value) });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
          {this.props.children.map(DropdownItem => {
            return DropdownItem;
          })}
        </select>
        <div>
          {this.state.value.split("\\n").map((item, i) => {
            return <p key={i}>{item}</p>;
          })}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Dropdown label="Dropdown Label">
    <DropdownItem
      label="1 main street \n sacramento, california"
      value="Number 1"
    />
    <DropdownItem
      label="2 main street \n stockton, california"
      value="Number 2"
    />
  </Dropdown>,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-counter-demo-vjocy

Comment: My design needs to have drop down and when they click the dropdown it should expand in this format                                                                           
                                                                                                                        
 233  (dropdown)

233 1 main street  (list view)
       sacramento

234  2 main street    (list view)
         stockton